# Jfrog pipelines - Is it possible to disable concurrent runs?

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

I have two runs - `Run 1` & `Run 2`. I want `Run 2` to wait until the `Run 1` is finished, how can I achieve this in jfrog pipelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this flag: `chronological: true` in your pipelines definition, which will allow your new runs of the pipeline to wait until the existing active runs are complete.

Please refer this documentation for more help https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Defining+a+Pipeline

> Any runs of the pipeline will not start running while another run of the same pipeline is processing if chronological is set to true. The default is false, allowing runs to execute in parallel if there are nodes available.